# how to get some element from each group after use groupby in spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have a spark rdd data, let's suppose it has 1000 elements and can be grouped into 10 groups, what I want to do is select 2 element which meets my special requirement in each group. And then, get a new rdd with 20 elements.

suppose the rdd data is like

```
((1,a1),
(1,a2),
(1,a3),
...
(1,a100),
(2,b1),
(2,b2),
(2,b3)
...
(2,b100))
```

what i want is

```
((1,a1),
(1,a99),
(2,b1),
(2,b99)
)
```

and I select a1、a99、b1、b99 with a function called my_func

I think the code may be something like：

```
myrdd.groupby(x => x._1)....(my_func)...
```

Comment: Need to be a bit more specific with an example. why rdd?

Comment: because the source data is hdfs, and I load it to rdd

Comment: you can load to DF as well. but an example is a good idea

Comment: OK, that is clearer.

Comment: spark or scala?

Comment: spark (using scala or python are both ok

Comment: What is the group by for?

Comment: groupby(x => x._1)

Comment: See  no need for that.

Comment: Might be polite to communicate with your helpers...

Answer (score 0):

Not convinced you need groupBy. Not sure of structure of RDD.

This using my own contrived data, so you will need to adapt:

```
// Gen some data. My data. Adapt to yours.
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((1, "x"), (2, "y"),  (3, "z"), (4, "z"), (5, "bbb") ))

// Compare list.
val l = List("x", "y", "z")

// Function to filter, could be inline or via mapPartitions.
def my_function(l: List[String], r: RDD[(Int, String)]) = {
    r.map(x => (x._1, x._2)).filter(x => l.contains(x._2)) 
}

// Run it all.
val rdd2 = my_function(l,rdd)
rdd2.collect
```

returns:

```
res24: Array[(Int, String)] = Array((1,x), (2,y), (3,z), (4,z))
```

Comment: I feel like a datafame solution would be better (select where in) than needing to compare an RDD with a serialized List

Comment: @OneCricketeer  Yes, look at my comments on question, but this was asked. So we agree. Maybe RDDs need to  be no longer used and removed, but I find zip still handy.

Comment: zip can be replaced by union, can't it?

Comment: @OneCricketeer zipWithIndex, sorry

Comment: the rdd origins from load a hdfs file by "sc.text()", should i transform the rdd to dataframe first?

Comment: No, that is fine. I just simulated input with an RDD from in memory. The answer answers your function question, but you need to load and consider how you map from file to tuples. But that is another question or you can google.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly discourage you from using `groupBy()` or even `mapPartitions()` for big dataset when you need to subsequently aggregate your data. The purpose of RDD and MapReduce programming model is to distribute computations: computing the max/min/sum etc in the driver or on a single node means using only the HDFS part of Spark.

Besides, there are many ways to perform your task, but focusing on finding a pattern that fits for every type of aggregation you need is just wrong and inevitably make your code inefficient.

Here is a possible PySpark solution for the problem you have:

```
rdd.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x if x < y else y)\
    .union(rdd.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x if x > y else y)).sortByKey().collect()
```

In the first `reduceByKey` I find the smallest value for each key and in the second one the biggest value for each key. Then I can `union` them and, **if necessary**, sort the resulting RDD to obtain the result you showed us.

Comment: interesting that you assume min and max is needed.

Comment: @thebluephantom sorry but I have not understood your point, what are you trying to say?